# Regular Expression with (too?) many cases

Tags: javascript, java, php, regex, regular-language

I'm struggling with a Regex since a few hours and don't seem to find the last bit of the solution. I'm basically parsing a C-Header files line-by-line to find variables.

Following the possible cases of lines I may encounter which need to pass the Regex:

```
//#define variable_name { 300 }

#define variable_name { 300 }

//#define variable_name

#define variable_name

//#define variable_name { 300 } // Comment

#define variable_name { 300 } // Comment

#define variable_name // Comment

//#define variable_name // Comment
```

The following rules apply to each line above:

- A line can start optionally with commenting slashes (i.e. //)
- `#define variable_name` will always be present
- A variable may optionally have a value (e.g. { 300 })
- The variable value (if present) may be of all possible types (Text, Number or Vector)
- A line may have a leading comment, either after the value or directly after the variable_name

I have been managing to create the following expression successfully up to the point of the optional variable value or optional comment:

`/^(\/\/)?(#define)\s(\w+)\s?(.*[\/\/]?)?`

The expression can be tested here: https://regex101.com/r/krZB71/3/

The problem I have is visible in the Group 4 of the fifth (5) and sixth (6) Match, the value and leading comment end up being grouped together... My aim is to **separately group** the variable_name, the optional value, the optional leading comment

I basically need help for the part after the `\s?`:

`/^(\/\/)?(#define)\s(\w+)\s? xxxxxxxxxx`

Any help highly appreciated

Comment: have you tried this `^(\/\/)?(#define)\s(\w+)\s?(\{.*\})?\s?(\/\/.*)?$`

Comment: You can make certain parts optional at the end and use the optional capture groups `^(\/\/)?(#define)\s(\w+)(?: ?({[^{}]*})? ?(\/\/ ?(.*))?)?` https://regex101.com/r/FP3YqN/1/

Comment: @Thefourthbird your solution is pretty neat, I like it that it even separates the leading  comment from it comments slashes

Comment: @kapreski your solution only kinda works. One thing I noticed, is that the variable value is hardcoded with curly brackets, while I mentioned above that it could be of any type. Nonetheless, I learned from your proposal, thanks!

Comment: @CRE8IT I have added it as an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that using the following expression separates the variable and the comment:

```
^(\/\/)?(#define)\s(\w+)\s?(.*?)(\/\/.*?)?$
```

Comment: very slim and working solution, thank you. I noticed though that I end up with empty groups in some cases which would have to be checked in my code

Comment: Isn't that what you would want? Now you can depend on the 4th group being the value, and not 'sometimes the variable, sometimes the comment'? Maybe I am not seeing your usecase, but that is what I'd want.

Comment: I added one more question mark and it works like a charm now without empty groups: ```^(\/\/)?(#define)\s(\w+)\s?(.*?)?(\/\/.*?)?$```

Comment: Great! Glad I could help!

Comment: your point about the 4th group always being the value is actually more than valid and ultimately simplifies the coding part. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

You could make the pattern a bit more specify and use optional capture groups to get the separate values.

```
^(\/\/)?(#define)\s(\w+)(?:\s?({[^{}]*})?\s?(\/\/\s?(.*))?)?
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\/\/)?` Optional **group 1**, match `//`
- `(#define)\s` Capture group 2, match `#define` and whitespace char
- `(\w+)` Capture **group 3** Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s?` Match optional whitespace char
  - `(` Optional capture **group 4**

    - `{[^{}]*}` Match `{`...`}`
  - `)?` Close group 4 and make it optional
  - `\s?` Match optional whitespace char
  - `(` Optional capture **group 5**

    - `\/\/\s?` Match `//` then optional whitespace char
    - `(.*)` Capture **group 6** match any char except a newline
  - `)?` Close group 5 and make it optional
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional so the whole last part is optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gRQ0ZE/1)

**Note** that `\s` also matches a newline. If you want to match whitespace chars without the newlines you could match tabs or spaces `[\t ]` or match a whitespace char except the newlines `[^\S\r\n]`.